# How to raise reputation number?

Tags: discussion

The sole reason i joined **AskDifferent** is to give a answer to question. But I was unable to do that as my answer contained two small pics and i didn't have **"Enough Reputation Points"**. So now my question is, **"How to raise my Reputation points?"**

Comment: Asking questions or answering questions increase your reputation. If someone upvotes your question you'll have enough reputation ;)

Comment: Try to answer your question without the pics -- I know it might take an extra thousand words or so ;-)

Comment: Put external links to the images - someone with enough rep will edit the question to put the images in the question

Answer (score 5):

The system restricts image embeds and multiple URL posts until you've gotten a few votes. This reduces the time needed to clean up after people that enjoy posting pictures of genetalia anonymously and such.

You can still upload a picture to any picture sharing site and paste the URL Into your question. Just add a comment aski someone to embed the picture and usually that happens within hours as most people are very helpful in editing new user's questions.

The [faq] covers reputation and how to earn it in many ways. Some easy ones are answering, making a helpful/substantial edit to a post or just asking a useful, well worded question.

Hopefully you figure some ways to answer and get votes.

Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 3):

Answer the question and when you get enough rep, you only need 9 points, then add the images to improve your answer.